# Xcode 15, ios 17 giving error in react native code - -[RTIInputSystemClient remoteTextInputSessionWithID:performInputOperation:] TextInput

Tags: react-native, xcode15, ios17

I have a React Native code and when I tried running it on `Xcode 15`, `iOS 17`

I am getting the error

> [RTIInputSystemClient remoteTextInputSessionWithID:performInputOperation:]  perform input operation requires a valid sessionID on the Otp screen which are 4 boxes of text.

It is working fine on `iOS 16`

Comment: Did you resolve this? Am getting same errors

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem. But in my case the issue was fixed in next Xcode version (current version is 15.0.1 (15A507)).